# How can I run a different dart file in Flutter?

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I have created a dart file other than `main.dart` file in which i have created a grid view. So now I cannot understand how can I run this file of my project!

[image]

Above is the picture of my Android Studio where these flutter files are located.
Please help me with running `demo.dart` file just like `main.dart` file of the project.

Comment: The main.dart file is by default the entry point for your Flutter Project! The demo.dart file is also part of the project, therefore if you want to access it from your main.dart file, you will simply have to add the import file definition. 
Imagining the root widget you want to create is defined on the demo.dart, you can the use RunApp() function and attached the widget defined on it as the argument of this function.

Comment: @AndréB can you please specify where should i write runApp()? Can you explain with an example?

Comment: It would be easier if you edit first your question with a minimal example of what you are trying to achieve, and most importantly what have you actually defined in your demo.dart file. Have you created any Widget there?

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/execute-only-dart-code-after-installing-flutter-e05ea9b46627

Comment: Don't know (yet, same issue), to install the Dart SDK: `choco install dart-sdk` ; to upgrade the Dart SDK: `choco upgrade dart-sdk`. Installation try to add PATH automatically.

Answer (score 16):

Do flutter run with -t option and the file.dart.

```
$flutter run -t lib/demo.dart
```

Comment: It doesn't run in the console instead it shows `Multiple devices found` like macOS, Chrome etc.

Comment: @iDecode You can specify the device with a `-d <device-id>`. Use `flutter devices` to find out the desired id. eg. `flutter run -d chrome -t lib/demo.dart`

Answer (score 6):

If you want `demo.dart` as the entry point of your app, you can right click on `demo.dart` and select `Run 'demo.dart'` (you need to define a `main` function in `demo.dart` to do so):

[image]

If you just want to use what you defined in `demo.dart` from `main.dart` you have to add an import statement at the beginning of the `main.dart` file:

`import 'demo.dart';`

then you can use your `GridView` defined in `demo.dart` inside `main.dart` (if the `GridView` is not private).

Comment: Great, but but running my file I receive an error `Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package:time_tracker_flutter_course/garbage.dart'.
hi` What does that mean?

Answer (score 6):

How run .dart file in terminal

1) Install Dart in your environment (if have not yet)

https://www.dartlang.org/tools/sdk#install

2) Add PATH variable for dart/bin

Example for Ubuntu

```
# add path example
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source .bashrc
```

3) And now just run your .dart file with the main() method in the terminal and see an output

```
$ dart path_to_your_file/your_file_with_main.dart
```

Comment: Error when reading `main.dart`: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 3):

first set path to your `Dart` sdk (now included in `flutter`).

1. if you create project using `flutter` and want to run separate single dart file let's say your file in `lib/mydart/` then in terminal path to `cd lib/mydart/` and `dart yourfile.dart`

**yourfile.dart**

```
void main() {
print('hello dart world');
}
```

2. if you simply create `.dart` (`hi.dart`) file in any directory then in terminal write `cd your_directory/` and run `dart hi.dart`

**hi.dart**

```
  void main() {
    print('hello dart world');
    }
```

you will see `hello dart world` output

Answer (score 2):

First create another dart file . As , I have created ***demo.dart*** file here.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      title: "Demo Application",
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("List Widget"),),
        body: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text("Apple"),
              trailing: new Icon(Icons.forward),
            ),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text("Banana"),
              trailing: new Icon(Icons.backpack),
            ),
            new ListTile(
              title: new Text("Hultrdds"),
              trailing: new Icon(Icons.approval),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

And then in your ***main.dart*** file  , import the ***demo.dart*** file and call like this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'demo.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(Demo());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After creating a flutter project
**to run a different dart file in Flutter**

1. you have to add main function like below code with you desire class name

   **void main() {
   runApp(newfile());
   }**
   or
   **void main() => runApp(newfile());**
2. then go to project bar of android studio right click on the selected file you will see Run'newfile.dart'
   then you will also see in the toolbar, select your app from the run **configurations drop-down menu**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

from the left file explorer ->right click -> **run**

Answer (score 0):

give import to the main.dart :-import 'Screens/demo.dart'; in main.dart
, then in the material app there is a home section where you have to give the class name of the demo.dart
[instead of ProfileScreenWidget() just write class name function present in the demo.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVNJH.png)

After this ,just run from above

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32906631)